# JS code to return n times an array not working

Tags: javascript

The following coding problem has me stumped.  There are four tests, which begin with "// ex."  They are followed by my code.  My code is only passing the first test.  I am unsure why it is failing the next 3.  Thanks in advance for any insight.

```
// 1.4 repeat(n, array)
// Write a function that takes a non-negative integer n and an array and           returns a new
// array that contains the contents of given array repeated n times.
// ex. repeat(0, [1]) -> []
// ex. repeat(10, []) -> []
// ex. repeat(1, [1, 2, 3]) -> [1, 2, 3]
// ex. repeat(3, [1, 2, 3]) -> [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

toolbox.repeat = function(n, array) {
  var arr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    arr.push(array);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: You can print out the result array to some where and see the different. It's basic problem.

Comment: You're creating an array of arrays, but the function is supposed to return an array of primitives.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is this line:

```
arr.push(array);
```

What this does is pushes the entire array as a single element, so you get:

```
[ [], [], ... n times ]
```

But what you want to do is push the contents of the array, `n` times.

One way you can solve this is to, instead of pushing, you concat `array` to `arr` on each iteration:

```
arr = arr.concat(array);
```

Another way would be to call `Array.prototype.push` and pass `arr` as the context into which to push and `array` as the arguments to be pushed:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(arr, array);
```

Or in ES6 you can use the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) operator to do the same:

```
arr.push(...array)
```

As [**self** demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40034266/3928341), you can also create an inner loop to, for every `n`, iterate over `array` and add its elements to `arr`.

Comment: This is certainly maybe more idiomatic. But I think it hides the implementation which may not be the best for this exercise.

Comment: yeah, that makes sense. I guess it depends on the exact purpose of the exercise but that's why I referenced your answer as well :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `array.concat` instead

```js
var repeat = function(n, array) {
  var arr = []
  for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    arr = arr.concat(array);
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(repeat(3,[1,2,3]))
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to push every value of array onto your new array *n* times. So you'll have an inner loop of:

```js
var repeat = function(n, array) {
  var arr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        arr.push(array[j]);
    }
  }
  console.log(arr);
}

repeat(0, [1])
repeat(10, [])
repeat(1, [1, 2, 3])
repeat(3, [1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work, OP needs to add the entire `array` to `arr` n times, not just attempt to copy contents once (assuming n is within bounds)

Comment: oh, you meant two loops, got ya, my bad.

Comment: Check my edit, i didn't realize he didn't have the first loop

Comment: Both of these methods were extremely helpful, thank you to everyone

Answer (score 0):

your code is incorrect, please change a little bit to

```
toolbox.repeat = function(n, array) {

  var arr = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // use concat array instead
    arr = arr.concat(array);

    return arr;
}

// repeat(0, [1]) -> []
// repeat(10, []) -> []
// repeat(1, [1, 2, 3]) -> [1, 2, 3]
// repeat(3, [1, 2, 3]) -> [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```